# Lynx thinks all certificates are untrusted with my configuration file

Tags: ssl, https, lynx

I am trying to visit what I'm assuming is a valid ssl-certified page, https://google.com, but lynx always says `SSL error:The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate is...-Continue? (n)`

I haven't done any configuration of lynx other than the following config file:

```
SET_COOKIES:TRUE
ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES:TRUE
PERSISTENT_COOKIES:TRUE
COOKIE_FILE:$home/.lynx_cookies
```

Why am I getting this warning and prompted to press "y" to proceed? I don't see the point if literally every site I'm visiting is untrusted.

To reproduce it, just `lynx -cfg=lynx.cfg https://google.com` with `lynx.cfg` as above.

---

**edit**

to answer some questions in comments.

the folder /etc/ssl/certs/ has a lot of stuff in it, im not going to list it all unless that's important.

running `ldd $(which lynx) |grep -i ssl` has no output.

the file /etc/lynx/lynx.cfg has this line `SSL_CERT_FILE:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` ... the other matches for `SSL_CERT` grep just seem to be comments

Running `openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443` shows this:

```
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
```

Comment: What is the content of your `/etc/ssl/certs/` folders. I guess you have an issue here. May be some missing root certificates.
Also what is the result of this command `ldd $(which lynx) |grep -i ssl` ?

Comment: AFAIK lynx uses OpenSSL, and google uses a cert chain that can end either in a now-dubious Equifax root or a newer GeoTrust one which [older versions of OpenSSL don't handle right](https://serverfault.com/a/841071/216633)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas edited question to include the output

Comment: @netmonk edited question to include the output

Comment: Do you get the same outcome if you run `lynx` as `SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt lynx https://google.com`? Does `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` exist on your system?

Comment: `lynx --version | head -3`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas specifying the `SSL_CERT_FILE` with the shell command fixed it. Lynx version is 2.8.9

Comment: You could try and run it under `strace -fo strace.log` to seen why it seems it's not loading /etc/lynx/lynx.cfg. Maybe it's looking for it elsewhere (look at the strace.log). Did you compile it from source yourself? Or maybe you had the SSL_CERT_FILE variable defined to something else?

Comment: The version (and platform) aren't stated.  There have been a couple of bug-reports related to the error-checking logic, needed for an informed answer.

Comment: If `ldd $(which lynx) |grep ssl` doesn't give any output, it's a bit strange, do you have something related to `tls` when you remove the `|grep ssl` and running the `ldd $(which lynx)` ?

Comment: @netmonk `libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f2cf1e04000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that when I loaded the custom config file with the `cfg=` option it no longer loaded the default config file at `/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg`.

Comment: You might find the [INCLUDE](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/master/lynx.cfg#L35) statement in lynx.cfg useful, for extending/amending the system defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the system's clock is correct. Browsers can show an SSL warning due to improper date and time.

Comment: At least according to the clock in gnome toolbar, it is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The message is (see [WWW/Library/Implementation/HTTP.c](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/lynx-snapshots/blob/master/WWW/Library/Implementation/HTTP.c#L1026)):

```
the certificate is not trusted
```

(there's no **`NOT`** in the source for lynx, notwithstanding its use in [Debian #795958](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=795958)).  That message comes from the gnutls configuration of lynx, making it likely that OP is using Debian or a derived distribution such as Ubuntu.  Everyone else packages using OpenSSL.

It could come from gnutls itself, as mentioned in *[[gnutls-devel] Unable to trust server certificate instead of issueing CA](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnutls-devel/2014-December/007270.html)*, but lacking version information, it's not possible to pinpoint the exact problem.

Barring some new bug report (and StackExchange by the way is not a bug-reporting mechanism), these changes have been related to that area of the code since it was introduced in 2006 (see [CHANGES](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html)). There are more recent gnutls changes, but nothing apparent in the change summary relevant to this question:

```
2013-11-28 (2.8.8dev.17)
* ignore non-fatal return codes from gnutls_handshake introduced by SNI change  
  in 2.8.8dev.15 (Debian #724812, patch by Hans Wurst).
2012-11-18 (2.8.8dev.15)
* improve checking of certificates in the gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2()    
  by handling special case where self-signed certificates should be reported    
  (patch by Jamie Strandboge).                                                   
2012-08-15 (2.8.8dev.13) 
* improve checking of certificates in the gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2()    
  (report by Martin Georgiev) -TD
2010-06-21 (2.8.8dev.4)                                                         
* check for SSL error when reading response from "GET".  This incidentally      
  exposes a longstanding bug in GNUTLS:                                         
    https://savannah.gnu.org/support/index.php?106987                           
  (google the message "A TLS packet with unexpected length was received")       
  which prevents connection to                                                  
    https://www.mynortonaccount.com/amsweb/default.do                           
  (report by Ignac Vucko) -TD 
2009-08-28 (2.8.8dev.1)
* correct check for return-value from gnutls_certificate_verify_peers2(), which 
  in conjunction with unclean internals of gnutls caused caused some sites to   
  be treated as if they were version-1 X.509 CAs (Debian #231609,               
  Ubuntu 293708) -TD
```

Both Debian and Ubuntu have bug-reporting systems; Debian provides the best feedback for lynx.  Followups to existing bug-reports (as well as new reports) should be directed to the bug-reporting systems.

Comment: From the comment to the question, it works when specifying the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable. I don't have a similar problem with the lynx packaged by Ubuntu or Debian. It sounds more like a configuration error.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh I think I get what was going on. You'll notice I said in the question `I haven't done any configuration of lynx other than the following config file:`. I was loading with `-cfg=` I realize now that this was overwriting the default config file, which I wasn't aware of because I didn't read the manual enough.

Comment: @maxple, that doesn't tie up with your _To reproduce it, just lynx https://google.com_

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know, I'm sorry